# Catalyst Instance has already disappeared: requested by FrescoModule

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

### Description

I am integrating react-native with cross-platform support, android (error found), ios (not tested), web (works correctly).

When creating the project with `rect-native init "app"` and installing with the `react-native run-android` command it works, but when installing react-native-web it gives me the error and trying again is where it gives me the error

### React Native version:

###### System:

```
OS: Windows 10 10.0.19043
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6500T CPU @ 2.50GHz
Memory: 2.98 GB / 15.88 GB
```

###### Binaries:

```
Node: 14.17.6 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
Yarn: Not Found
npm: 7.21.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
Watchman: Not Found
```

###### SDKs:

```
Android SDK: Not Found
Windows SDK:
  AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense: Enabled
```

###### IDEs:

```
Android Studio: Version     2020.3.0.0 AI-203.7717.56.2031.7678000
Visual Studio: Not Found
```

###### Languages:

```
Java: 15.0.1
```

###### npmPackages:

```
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
react-native: 0.65.1 => 0.65.1
react-native-windows: Not Found
```

###### npmGlobalPackages:

```
*react-native*: Not Found
```

### Steps To Reproduce

1. `react-native init 'Name'`
2. ingregrate react-native-web from steps https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/installation/
3. apply extra configuration for react-native-web from here https://arry.medium.com/how-to-add-react-native-web-to-an-existing-react-native-project-eb98c952c12f
4. `react-native run-android`

### Expected Results

App run correctly

### links (same from the top):

https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/installation/
https://arry.medium.com/how-to-add-react-native-web-to-an-existing-react-native-project-eb98c952c12f